# How can we retain dropdown list value, when we select the option?

Tags: forms

I want to retain dropdown list value, so that when ever someone select the option from the dropdown list should retain that value after performing the action.

```
/*
 *implements hook_menu().
 */

function dropdown_page_menu(){
  $items = array();
  $items['page/layout/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'Select Layout',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('dropdown_page_select_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    );

  return $items;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_block_info().
 */
function dropdown_page_block_info() {
    $blocks = array();

    $blocks['dropdown_page_select_form'] = array(
        'info' => t('Select Layout'),
    );

    return $blocks;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_block_view().
 */
function dropdown_page_block_view($delta = '') {
    $block = array();

    switch ($delta) {
        case 'dropdown_page_select_form':
            $block['subject'] = t('Select Layout');
            $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('dropdown_page_select_form');
            break;
    }

    return $block;
}


function dropdown_page_select_form($form, &$form_state){
  $options = array(
    'select' => t('Select'),
    'layout_1' => t('Layout 1'),
    'layout_2' => t('Layout 2'),
    'layout_3' => t('Layout 3'),
    );

  $form['choice'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => $options,
    '#title' => t('Select your layout'),
    '#default_value' => $form_state['choice']['type']
    );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value'=> t('Go'),
    );
  return $form;
}

function dropdown_page_select_form_submit($form, &$form_state){


switch ($form_state['values']['choice']){
  case layout_1 : {

    //echo 'hi';die;
    drupal_goto("layout_1".$options);
    break;


  }
  case layout_2 : {  
    //echo 'no';die;
    drupal_goto("layout_2".$options);
    break;
  }
  case layout_3 : {  
    drupal_goto("layout_3".$options);
    break;
  }
  default: {
    print 'Select it!';
  }
}



  drupal_set_message(t('Your layout %input', array('%input' => $form_state['value']['choice'])));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code. I think you need this value to be retained through all pages while navigating.

```
function dropdown_page_select_form($form, &$form_state) {
    $options = array(
        'select' => t('Select'),
        'layout_1' => t('Layout 1'),
        'layout_2' => t('Layout 2'),
        'layout_3' => t('Layout 3'),
    );

    $form['choice'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#options' => $options,
        '#title' => t('Select your layout'),
        '#default_value' => isset($_SESSION['selected_layout']) ? $_SESSION['selected_layout'] : 'select'
    );
    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Go'),
    );
    return $form;
}

function dropdown_page_select_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    $_SESSION['selected_layout'] = $form_state['values']['choice'];
    drupal_set_message(t('Your layout %input', array('%input' => $form_state['value']['choice'])));
    switch ($form_state['values']['choice']) {
        case 'layout_1' : {

                //echo 'hi';die;
                drupal_goto("layout_1" . $options);
                break;
            }
        case 'layout_2' : {
                //echo 'no';die;
                drupal_goto("layout_2" . $options);
                break;
            }
        case 'layout_3' : {
                drupal_goto("layout_3" . $options);
                break;
            }
        default: {
                print 'Select it!';
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default values as follows,

`$form['choice'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => $options,
    '#title' => t('Select your layout'),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('choice', $form_state['choice']['type']
)
);`

provided you get the submitted values in the variable $form_state['choice']['type'] post submit action.
And the variable name should match the form field name "choice"

Hope this works for you!

Comment: it's not working